# Using boost/python on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost-python

I'm trying to get into C++-extensions for python, with boost/python.

I've downloaded boost 1_73 and installed it by calling `bootstrap` and then `b2 --with-python`

In Visual Studio, i've included the compiler include path (the boost directory) and linker library paths (/stage/lib/) that the output of b2 tells me to.

Now I get the compiler error `LNK1104 cannot open file 'boost_python37-vc141-mt-x64-1_73.lib'`. I can't find any information about this specific error. For everything similar there is only the suggestion to add the above mentioned paths.

The code I'm trying to compile is just the hello world example supplied with boost.

Any ideas?

Comment: As it sounds like you're just starting out on this I'd recommend you took a look at [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as an alternative to boost python. It's header only which make life a lot easier.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions, I will have a look at that, too. I still want/need to understand boost for an existing project I'm trying to get involved in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check that file exists somewhere in your filesystem. If it doesn't, you may have accidentally built it against a different version (i.e. not 141) of the VC runtime. (This has happened to me when I've had multiple runtimes installed.)

If you do have the file, then you just need to ensure that the path is in the link settings section of your project config.

Comment: Good hint, that was it. In fact, I hadn't compiled boost properly or against VS at all. I then still had the problem that the boost_python-libs weren't included, but now I have found out about the user-config.jam file and it compiled. Thanks!